# Is it possible to integrate GPS system in an asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gps

One of my client wants to track his cars/cabs from his own house... So i thought of getting help from our fellow users of SO... Is it possible to integrate GPS system in an asp.net web application? If so,How to get started...

**EDIT:**
Any webservice that does it for me? Should i use google maps api? I dont know where to start.. Any suggestion..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most [GPRS-enabled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gprs) [vehicle trackers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Tracker#Data_pushers) can be configured to send the position data periodically to a remote server. The protocol and the details of the connection will vary a lot between different manufacturers. However in most cases, you should be able to configure the tracking device with the IP address and TCP port of your server, and then you should set up an application at that endpoint that listens for TCP connections from the tracking devices. This back-end application can then push the data it receives into a database, from where your ASP.NET web application would be able to retrieve the data.

The first thing you should check is the documentation of the tracking device, if this was already chosen by your client. The serious brands will even provide working examples and demonstrations.

When you solve that part, and you start getting the data in the database, it will be a matter of serving the information from the database through your ASP.NET web application. To have the vehicles moving in real-time, you should probably look into [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) or [long-polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) or SignalR.

As for Google Maps, note that the you cannot use the free version for vehicle tracking. Article 10.9.C of [Google Maps API Terms and Conditions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) explicitly prohibits using the standard (free) Google Maps API for non-public fleet management and asset tracking. You would need the [Google Maps API Premier](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html) to legally use Google Maps for these kinds of applications.

As an additional side-note, according to one [unofficial source](http://osdir.com/ml/GoogleMapsAPI/2010-04/msg00187.html) (dated April 2008), the Premier API for vehicle tracking would cost USD 10,000 per year, which entitles you to track 100 vehicles. If you exceed the 100 vehicles, you would need to add USD 24 per additional vehicle per year.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is `yes you can`! Look at this [link](http://www.gpsintegrated.com/Services/PersonalGPSTracking.aspx) to give you an idea how this works. There are many techniques and this web page explains how you can utilise this type of technology. Howeever you are still going to need to expose some web services and then provide a Google map on webpage that updates its self via AJAX every x seconds.

> **What Is Personal GPS Tracking?**
>
> Personal Tracking is a system, where a
>   person or an commodity can be  tracked
>   using devices that are integrated with
>   Global positioning System (GPS)  and
>   Global Service for Mobiles (GSM).
>
> You can carry it in your pocket like
>   mobile phone or can install it in your
>   car to get the location on SMS or web
>   based services provided by GPS
>   Integrated.

Answer (score 1):

The [GPS Gate server](http://gpsgate.com/products/gpsgate_server) does exactly what you want I think. Combine it with any of the compatible trackers and you can track several vehicles for no cost. It's very comprehensive, well written, stable software. It's free for up to 5 vehicles, but after that you need a commercial license.

If any functionality you need is missing, you can extend it with a plugin (lots of different types of plugin are supported), or even make your own interface to the data it collects (which is stored in a SQL database).